# eclipse shows 'out of memory' while it is ok in heap status bar

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, configuration, out-of-memory

I am running JUnit Test.

My heap space is MAX 497M.(according to eclipse status bar)

My the other program take over 441 when it beginning. However, the test what I am trying to ran show 'out of memory'.(It only takes 304)

I do not know why and is there any check list such a situation like this?

Below is my error message:

```
SRCTest.testChannelsWithPrograms
testChannelsWithPrograms(com.test.svc.SRCTest)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:490)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:771)
    at com.zinnaworks.test.svc.SRCTest.testChannelsWithPrograms(SRCTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
```

Thanks ^^b

===============================================================================

attaching part of codes for better solution :D

```
public class ProgramTbody {
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> injectProgram2Channel (
            List<Map<String, Object>> channelList, List<Map<String, Object>> programList) throws Exception {

        List<Map<String, Object>> returnChannelArray = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        for(int i = channelList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            Map<String, Object> returnElement = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            returnElement.putAll(channelList.get(i));

            String sid = returnElement.get("SID").toString();
            List<Map<String, Object>> programsForChannel = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

            for(int j = programList.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                if(programList.get(j).get("SID").equals(sid)){
                    programsForChannel.add(programList.get(j));
                    programList.remove(j);
                }
            }

            returnElement.put("pros", programsForChannel);
            returnChannelArray.add(returnElement);
            channelList.remove(i);
        }
        return returnChannelArray;
    }
};
```

Comment: The JVM needs the memory to be contiguous.  E.g. If you want to copy a 100MB array, then more than 100MB needs to be contiguous.  Simply having 200MB is not good enough.

Comment: What method are you using to determine that "It only takes 304"?

Comment: @merlin2011 I am not sure what that number exactly represents, but it called 'eclipse heap status bar'. it shows heap memory usage as form of bar graph.

Comment: @JuneyoungOh, Is it possible that the heap was only 304 immediately before the Array copy and then the array copy pushed it over the edge before Eclipse could detect it?

Comment: @Java1 according to eclipse heap status bar, It only takes 304M while maximum is 497M.

Comment: @merlin2011 Maybe. But I do not know how to check this. The task is just copy an 'List<Map<String,Object>' to another same type. So I tried remove element as soon as copied, but did not work

Comment: @JuneyoungOh, The Java garbage collector does not collect items as soon as you remove them.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to understand exactly what is happening with the memory?
Or are you just trying to make it work? Because you can do that just by increasing memory.

Comment: @merlin2011 Sorry if you confused. My goal is make this work without editing any configurations(e.g. adding java heap space extends options).

Comment: It does not not look like you have included the line that throws the exception. The stack trace mentions `testChannelsWithPrograms` as the first non-library line but I do not see it in your code.

Comment: @merlin2011 Oh! That one is JUnit Test method, it just Inject a bean which have the method above. I doubt that this error occurs while copy ArrayList sine when I make this method to comment it works. If posting JUnit test can be helpful I can post that also.

Comment: The exception indicates that the exception happened during a call of "java.io.PrintStream.println". You need to show where the `println` is happening.

Comment: @merlin2011 Indeed println was a problem. thanks:D Can you add a post as 'Answer Your Question'. So I can close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception indicates that the exception happened during a call of "java.io.PrintStream.println". You need to find the line where the `println` is happening and possibly remove it.